# Пример использования функции removeWidget() в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Не могли бы вы привести пример использования функции `removeWidget()` в PyQt5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя [`RemoveWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#removeWidget) в `QVBoxLayout` вы его удаляете из макета выбранный виджет в данном случае это виджеты `QTextEdit` и `QPushButton`, тем самым можете назначить его позицию `(resize)` как в примере:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('TextEdit')
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.setFont(QFont('Times', 13))
        self.text_edit = QTextEdit(self)
        self.button = QPushButton()
        self.button.setText('удалить все объекты из QVBoxLayout')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.del_box)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.text_edit)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def del_box(self):
        self.layout.removeWidget(self.text_edit)
        self.layout.removeWidget(self.button)
        self.text_edit.resize(200, 50)
        self.button.move(0, 100)
        self.button.resize(300, 30)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```